# Questions regarding indirect effects mediation regession

Tags: multiple-regression, mediation

I am trying to test the significance of the total indirect effects of 3 variables and I am required to use multiple regression modelling (the mediators were unintended). While I found an equation from Preacher and Hayes (2008) (see image) and I am assuming that $s_{b_{1}b_{2}}$ means cov($b_{1}$,$b_{2}$) and so on. If so, I don't think its possible to calculate the standard error of $a_{1}*b_{1}+a_{2}*b_{2}+a_{3}*b_{3}$ for the path analysis in image 2 (blue is 3 univariate regressions while black corresponds to the partial regressions of the direct effects of the mediating variables on the dependent variable). $a_{i} and b_{i}$ correspond to the a and b values in the formula in image 1.

But my question is this: can I use $\frac{c - c'}{\sqrt{\text{SE}(c)^2 + \text{SE}(c')^2}}$ instead of the var[f] formula in image 1?
In short does $$
\frac{a \cdot b}{\sqrt{a^2 \cdot \text{SE}(b)^2 + b^2 \cdot \text{SE}(a)^2}} = \frac{c - c'}{\sqrt{\text{SE}(c)^2 + \text{SE}(c')^2}}
$$

[image]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Whelp, after a bit of logical reasoning and plotting of the z-score formula with the covariance term $cov(c,c')$ being x from 0 to 0.0001,it seems that my assumption is correct as the value of 0 for $cov(c,c')$ results in the lowest possible z-score given that c and c' involve the same IV and DV, meaning that $cov(c,c')$ must be non-negative and any positive value will only make the denominator smaller, thereby increasing the magnitude of the test statistic.

Though, if I am wrong in this conclusion, please feel free to correct me.